# OpenRewrite: how to visit sourceFiles with a custom extension in a JAVA Project?

Tags: java, openrewrite

I am creating a recipe to modify a final JAVA project according to certain conditions.

The use case would be:

- IF there is a file called "file.test" in the project.
- THEN I add a maven property to the project's pom.xml

It seems simple, but I can't get any Visitor to handle a file with *.test extension.

For example I have tried the following:

```
static class MarkerRecipe extends Recipe {

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
      return "arker Recipe";
    }

    @Override
    protected TreeVisitor<?, ExecutionContext> getSingleSourceApplicableTest() {
      return new HasSourcePath<>("**/*.test");
    }

    @Override
    protected PlainTextVisitor<ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
      return new PlainTextVisitor<ExecutionContext>() {
        @Override
        public @Nullable PlainText postVisit(final PlainText tree, final ExecutionContext executionContext) {
          if (tree.getSourcePath().toString().endsWith("file.test")) {
            // Add maven Property
            MarkerRecipe.this.doNext(new ChangePropertyValue("maven-property", "to fill!", true));
          }
          return super.postVisit(tree, executionContext);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

I have also tried using the `org.openrewrite.FindSourceFiles` Recipe as follows by adding it to my princpipal recipe and debugging to see if it detects *.test file types:

```
    this.doNext(new FindSourceFiles("*.test"));
```

I have created `.test` files both inside `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/main/files`, but nothing works...

any idea?

I'm using open-rewrite 7.22.0

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the new [Quark](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-core/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/quark/Quark.java) which was introduced in rewrite [7.23.0](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/releases/tag/v7.23.0). Now the build plugins will add a Quark with a Path and Markers to the source set for each file not supported by any other parser.

Comment: With the new Quark it can be done perfectly! 

More information can be found here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/1787